# Mixing asp.net mvc controllers/views and static content management pages from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to build my first page using asp.net mvc3/razor which will mix pages showing entities like a list of news items and pages loaded from database created from a wysiwyg form (=content management page, cm). Therefore I would like all cm pages to use the same controller/view.

One "ugly" way to solve it is using a Pages action on each controller but I rather have a way to lookup if the link is an action or should be loaded from DB. Can I create routes like that? And if I can should I or is there a better solution?

For example if I have this structure

- **Home** (Controller)

  - **News** (Action, page built up dynamically using list of news items)
  - **About** (Action, page from db)
  - **Contact** (Action, page from db)
  - **Calendar** (Action, page built up dynamically using a list of calendar events)
- **Orienteering** (controller)

  - **What is orienteering** (Action, page from db)

I would like the url to the **About** page to be /Home/About not Home/Pages/About and the **What is orienteering** to be Orienteering/What-is-orienteering. These two pages are created from a wysiwyg editor in the gui by the users.

The **News** and **Calendar** should be loaded like standard controller/view page.

The bottomline is that I would like a base set of dynamic pages displaying structured data and on top of that the users should be able to create new pages from that GUI that is not controllers/view but loaded directly from the database.

I could create a Pages controller but then the URLs won't mirror the menu the user is seeing.

What is best practise in this case? :)